# Create null rows when there is no data for the combinations in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sas, proc-sql

Most of people might have asked about this and I did tried as well but couldnt get a solution. I have a table with 15 attributes/columns with non measures and 15 columns with measures. for the non measure columns - I want to create null values if anyof the combinations do not exists. I am using SAS which can have simple PROC SQL statements. Lets say I have the data like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu6JO.png)

```
Name | Location | Holiday | Time | DishCnt | TastedGood
Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    AM       3          Yes
Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    PM       3          Yes
Bill    1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          Yes
Bill    2st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          Yes
Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    PM       2          Yes
Sameer  1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       1          Yes
Peter   1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
Peter   1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          No
```

I want to check for each non measurerows the combinations, if it doesnt then I want to create a new row and put it as null or 0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kDBf.png)
The sample data I want to have looks like this:

```
Name | Location | Holiday | Time | DishCnt | TastedGood
Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    AM       3          Yes
Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    PM       3          Yes
Bill    1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          Yes
Bill    2st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          Yes
Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    PM       2          Yes
Sameer  1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       1          Yes
Sameer  2st Fl.    Kawanza   AM      NULL        NULL
Peter   1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
Peter   1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          No
Peter   1st Fl.    Easter    PM      NULL        NULL
Peter   2st Fl.    Kawanza   AM      NULL        NULL
```

Code I did was I try to cross join the same table and joined with the common columns. something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Holidays H
CROSS JOIN Holidays T
LEFT JOIN Holidays R ON H.HoludayKey = R.HolidayKey AND T.TimeKey=R.TimeKey
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: Somewhere I am doing wrong. It ended up with the Cartesian product. I result is doubled and giving inaccurate data

Answer (score 2):

Consider a cross joined dataset for all possible values of Name, Location, Holiday, and Time. Then run this query with a `LEFT JOIN` to actual dataset. Any unmatched rows will fill with `NULL` or missing.

```sql
proc sql;
   CREATE TABLE combns AS
   SELECT n.Name
        , m.Location
        , m.Holiday
        , m.Time
   FROM 
       (SELECT DISTINCT Name
        FROM Holidays) n
   CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT Location, Holiday, Time
        FROM Holidays) m;
   
   CREATE TABLE final_table AS
   SELECT c.Name
        , c.Location
        , c.Holiday
        , c.Time
        , h.DishCnt
        , h.TastedGood
   FROM combns c
   LEFT JOIN Holidays h
    ON c.Name = h.Name 
    AND c.Location = h.Location
    AND c.Holiday = h.Holiday
    AND c.Time = h.Time;
quit;
```

---

**Input** *(OP's posted data)*

```
data Holidays;
    infile datalines delimiter=',' DSD; 
    length Name $8 Location $8 Holiday $8 Time $2 DishCnt TastedGood $3;
    
    input Name Location Holiday Time DishCnt TastedGood;
    datalines;
Bill,1st Fl.,Easter,AM,3,Yes
Bill,1st Fl.,Easter,PM,3,Yes
Bill,1st Fl.,Kawanza,AM,2,Yes
Bill,2st Fl.,Kawanza,AM,2,Yes
Sameer,1st Fl.,Easter,AM,1,No
Sameer,1st Fl.,Easter,PM,2,Yes
Sameer,1st Fl.,Kawanza,AM,1,Yes
Peter,1st Fl.,Easter,AM,1,No
Peter,1st Fl.,Kawanza,AM,2,No
;
```

**Output** *(after running above `proc sql`)*

[image: Data Output]

Comment: Thanks for the work but I tried and I was not successfull. I can see my measures doubled up and are not same.

Comment: Possibly your actual data differs from what you posted. I edited my answer to show my `proc sql` solution works with your posted data to render your desired results (with rows not ordered exactly).